# Cannot choose between multiple constructors with equal length 1 on type 'System.String'

Tags: string, autofac

I am getting the following error when trying to resolve a type:

> Cannot choose between multiple constructors with equal length 1 on type 'System.String'. Select the constructor explicitly, with the UsingConstructor() configuration method, when the component is registered.

The type has 1 constructor that takes an `IRepository` and an `ILog` so I don't really know where the `System.String` is coming in to the picture.  I'm perplexed.  Does anyone have any idea what the problem is?

Here is the stack trace:

> at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.MostParametersConstructorSelector.SelectConstructorBinding(ConstructorParameterBinding[] constructorBindings)
>      at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.AutowiringParameter.<>c_*DisplayClass2.b*_0()
>      at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()
>      at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.AutowiringParameter.<>c_*DisplayClass2.b*_0()
>      at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()
>      at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
>      at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType)
>      at SomeCompany.ComponentModel.Composition.AutofacIocContainer.Resolve(Type type) in c:\SomeCompany.Core\ComponentModel\Composition\AutofacIocContainer.cs:line 17
>      at SomeCompany.Commands.CommandFactory.Create(String name) in c:\SomeCompany.Core\Commands\CommandFactory.cs:line 28
>      at SomeCompany.Web.Controllers.CommandsController.Post(String id, String request) in c:\SomeCompany.Web\Controllers\CommandsController.cs:line 49
>      at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
>      at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass13.<GetExecutor>b__c(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
>      at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
>      at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.<>c__DisplayClass5.<ExecuteAsync>b__4()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Comment: What do IRepository and ILog resolve to? The constructors for the classes implementing those interfaces might take a string param, or they could take dependencies which have a constructor with a string param, etc.

Comment: Please show your configuration and the definition of the type being resolved. Could it be that one of its dependencies (`IRepository`, `ILog`, or their dependencies recursively) contain multiple constructors? Doensn't Autofac throw in a type name (in the inner exception perhaps)?

Comment: Sorry guys, the company I was working for at this time shipped much of their dev offshore and I, along with many others, were casualties. I hope they get exactly what they pay for :) Thank you for the answers though! I'm pretty sure I resolved this but I did not fulfill my duty to update this question and for that, I apologize.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with multiple constuctors on your own code!

Autofac automatically creates objects for the constructor of your subject when you don't set them explicitly yourself.

However, when your constructor has a String parameter, it can not create a string, as String does not have a parameterless constructor! <sup>[1]</sup>

You need to set all strings on the constructor of your subject explicitly. You can also use NamedParameters and give Strings an explicit value.

Good luck!

<sub>[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx</sub>

Comment: This is the correct answer, however what would be nice is some more informative debug information from Autofac, when you have a reasonably complex container wired up trawling through all the dependencies to find the one with a string in it is a bit painful.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a database-definition file (.dbml), check for modifications to the code that you didn't make. In my case, the following method

```
public JudicialDataContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString, mappingSource)
{
    OnCreated();
}
```

was changed to this:

```
public JudicialDataContext(string connection) : base(connection, mappingSource)
{
    OnCreated();
}
```

I have no idea why it did this, or what it is trying to accomplish by doing this, or why this change would even be necessary. But discarding the change and recompiling overcame this error.