# Cannot choose between multiple constructors with equal length 1 on type 'System.String' with autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

**I get that exception**:

> Exception thrown: 'Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException' in Autofac.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot choose between multiple constructors with equal length 1 on type 'System.String'. Select the constructor explicitly, with the UsingConstructor() configuration method, when the component is registered.

**Stacktrace**:

```
 at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.MostParametersConstructorSelector.SelectConstructorBinding(ConstructorParameterBinding[] constructorBindings)
```

**when I do**:

container.Resolve();

**How I register my service**:

```
builder.RegisterType<CustomerService>()
       .As<ICustomerProcessingUnit>()
       .WithParameter("MyUrl", AppSettings.Default.MyUrl);
```

How I resolve my service:

```
var customerService = container.Resolve<CustomerService>();
```

**My CustomerService class**:

```
public class CustomerService: CustomerProcessingUnitBase 
    {
        private string myUrl;
        private readonly ISendService sendService;

        public CustomerService(ISendService sendService, string myUrl)
        {
            this.sendService = sendService;
            this.myUrl= myUrl;
        }
}
```

In **ICustomerProcessingUnit.cs** file:

```
 public interface ICustomerProcessingUnit
 {
    Task ProcessAsync();
 }

    public abstract class CustomerProcessingUnitBase : ICustomerProcessingUnit
    {
        public abstract Task ProcessAsync();

        public void Process()
        {
            this.ProcessAsync().Wait();
        }
    }
```

Why do I get that exception?

I know this: [Cannot choose between multiple constructors with equal length 1 on type 'System.String'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977694/cannot-choose-between-multiple-constructors-with-equal-length-1-on-type-system)

But why should *Autofac* create a string? I inject it! See my .Register call passing the string as parameter.

Comment: Could you share the stack trace ?

Comment: could you post the full stack trace ant not only the first line ? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I created a test app using Autofac 3.5.2 using the code below, note that I had to change the resolve from `container.Resolve<CustomerService>();` to `container.Resolve<ICustomerProcessingUnit>();` otherwise the following exception was thrown:

> Unhandled Exception: Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException:
>   The requested service 'ConsoleApplication7.CustomerService' has not been registe
>   red. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service
>   , check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptiona
>   l() method to resolve an optional dependency.

This code works though so I suspect you have something else going on which you haven't detailed.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<SendService>().As<ISendService>();

        builder.RegisterType<CustomerService>()
            .As<ICustomerProcessingUnit>()
            .WithParameter("myUrl", AppSettings.Default.MyUrl);

        var container = builder.Build();

        var customerService = container.Resolve<ICustomerProcessingUnit>();
    }
}

public class SendService : ISendService
{
}

public interface ISendService
{
}

public interface ICustomerProcessingUnit
{
    Task ProcessAsync();
}

public abstract class CustomerProcessingUnitBase : ICustomerProcessingUnit
{
    public abstract Task ProcessAsync();

    public void Process()
    {
        this.ProcessAsync().Wait();
    }
}

public class CustomerService : CustomerProcessingUnitBase
{
    private string myUrl;
    private readonly ISendService sendService;

    public CustomerService(ISendService sendService, string myUrl)
    {
        this.sendService = sendService;
        this.myUrl = myUrl;
    }

    public override Task ProcessAsync()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: You do it like me. But when I do in the register code this:          .WithParameter(new TypedParameter(typeof(string), MyUrlValue)); that kind worked!

Comment: oh thats not funny anymore. As I said after resolve I get the customerService instance but when I pass this instance to other methods suddenly I get that former exception again. But I could debug that the .Resolve really injected my string url. We make heavy usage of AutoFac maybe its a problem with the Modules. Gotta talk to my colleague and debug with him.